# How to iterate over []map[string]interface{} in Go to generate html table

Tags: go, go-html-template

Am trying to generate a HTML content using `html/template` in `Go` . The data is actually an output of `SELECT` query from different `MySQL` Tables.

I need help on the below

1. Am able to generate the HTML but am unable to split the rows. How to iterate over `result := []map[string]interface{}{}` (I use interface since the number of columns and it's type are unknown prior to execution) to present data in a table format ?
2. The Columns and Rows aren't matching

**Note**: Currently `result` in the playground link contains 2 maps which should be considered as dynamic. It will change depending on the target table.

Here is the playground link which has sample data matching my use case.
https://go.dev/play/p/UTL_j1iRyoG

Below is the output HTML which adds all the values as single row which also doesn't match with Columns.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My page</title>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        th, td {
          padding: 10px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Colour</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Red</td><td>Apple</td><td>Banana</td><td>Yellow</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keyword: Type `switch`.

Comment: @mkopriva - It works as expected ! You are awesome :-) 
Can you please submit it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```golang
var cols []string
var rows [][]interface{}

for key, _ := range result[0] {
    cols = append(cols, key)
}

for _, res := range result {
    vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for i, col := range cols {
        vals[i] = res[col]
    }
    rows = append(rows, vals)
}
```

```golang
data := struct {
    Title   string
    Columns []string
    Rows    [][]interface{}
}{
    Title:   "My page",
    Columns: cols,
    Rows:    rows,
}
```

And the HTML will need to be modified accordingly:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    {{range .Columns}}<th>{{ . }}</th>{{else}}<div><strong>no rows</strong></div>{{end}}
    </tr>
    {{- range .Rows}}
    <tr>
    {{range .}}<td>{{ . }}</td>{{end}}
    </tr>
    {{- end}}
</table>
```

https://go.dev/play/p/MPJOMlfQ488

---

Note that in Go maps are unordered, so looping over `result[0]` to aggregate the column names will produce an unordered `[]string`. This means that the user viewing your HTML page multiple times will see inconsistent output. If that's something you want to avoid, you could either choose to sort the columns using package [`sort`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort@go1.18.4), or you could opt to retain the order of [`sql.Rows.Columns`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.4#Rows.Columns) in some way.